# I am not able to post my values in child class of sql server

Tags: android, sql

In my android project i am putting my data through post request currently i am using ion library.i am able to post values in parent class but when i post my data in child class it shows null fields.its been 2 days i am trying but failed.

```
        JSONObject address = new JSONObject();
        address.put("StateProvinceId", "23");
        address.put("PhoneNumber", "hjuhu");
        address.put("ZipPostalCode", "hjuhu");
        address.put("City", "hjuhu");
        address.put("County", "hjuhu");
        address.put("Address1", "hjuhu");
        address.put("Address2", "hjuhu");
        address.put("FaxNumber", "hjuhu");




        Ion.with(getActivity())
            .load("http://192.168.10.150:81/Api/Customers/PostCustomerSave")
            .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .setHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + token)

            .setBodyParameter("Name", "hjuhu")
            .setBodyParameter("Ssn", "2309346")
            .setBodyParameter("CompanyId", "3")
            .setBodyParameter("CompanyName", "hjuhu")
            .setBodyParameter("CreatedBy", "3")
            .setBodyParameter("UpdatedBy", "3")
            .setBodyParameter("CreatedDate", "8/5/2019")
            .setBodyParameter("UpdatedBy", "8/5/2019")
```

> Here i am sending my child data in crm_address.

```
                .setBodyParameter("CRM_Address[]", 
              String.valueOf(address))
            .asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
```

> and this the model class of server api where i am putting my data i had successfully posted my data in crm customer but not in crm address.

```
      public class CRM_CustomerDm
{


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title_Name { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string MI_Name { get; set; }
    public string Jobtitle { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryPhone { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryPhone { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryMobile { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryMobile { get; set; }
    public string C_Email { get; set; }
    public string C_CC_Email { get; set; }
    public string C_Other1 { get; set; }
    public string C_Other2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> CreditLimit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> OpeningBalance { get; set; }
    public decimal Cust_Balance { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TillDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public bool SameAddress { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C_Detail_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C_Sub_ID { get; set; }
    public string Faderal_EIN { get; set; }
    public string Tax_ID { get; set; }
    public string Licencse { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Licencse_Expire { get; set; }
```

> here is the child crm address it giving null value on post.

```
    public virtual ICollection<CRM_AddressDm> CRM_Address { get; set; }
    CRM_CustomerAttachments { get; set; }
    }
```